# Throw a gulp-notify message when gulp-eslint fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-notify

I'm trying to use gulp-notify when my ESlint task detect errors, but I can't make it work, since gulp-notify needs to be referenced with a pipe after some Node.js stream.

I can "make it work" partially with the following code:

```
return gulp.src([config.js.all, '!app/assets/scripts/vendor/**'])
.pipe(eslint())
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(eslint.format())
.pipe(notify('Error!!!'))
.pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

However that throws the message always, not only when I have errors.

I can get the errors in gulp-eslint using the following syntax:

```
return gulp.src([config.js.all, '!app/assets/scripts/vendor/**'])
.pipe(eslint())
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(eslint.format())
.pipe(notify('Error!!!'))
.pipe(eslint.result(function (result) {
    if(result.errorCount > 0){
        console.log('Error');
    }
}))
.pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

That returns me the console.log when there are errors, what I need is to make gulp-notify to send a notification inside the above code. Could someone help me?

Comment: I just found the solution indirectly from this Jshint similar question: [JShint question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115226/cant-make-gulp-notify-to-pop-up-a-error-message-when-gulp-jshint-fail)
```
    gulp.task('eslint', () => {
      return gulp.src([config.js.all, '!app/assets/scripts/vendor/**'])
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
        .on('error', notify.onError({ message: 'JS error'}));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36207827/984275) is almost right.  Here's how to fix it:

```
return gulp.src([config.js.all, '!app/assets/scripts/vendor/**'])
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(eslint.format())
  .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
  .on("error", notify.onError('Error!!!')); // <-- notify after eslint.failAfterError
```

Simple enough. Happy linting!

Comment: But this will end your gulp stream. Any examples out there without gulp bailing out at `eslint.failAfterError()` ?

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-notify documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify#notifyonerror) gives a few examples. in your case, it should look like this:

```
return gulp.src([config.js.all, '!app/assets/scripts/vendor/**'])
.pipe(eslint())
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(eslint.format())
.on("error",notify.onError('Error!!!'))
.pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```